# f# array.filter based on a bool array

Tags: f#

if I have array `A`, and I have another bool array `isChosen` with the same length of `A` how can I build a new array from `A` where `isChosen` is `true`? something like `A.[isChosen]`? I cannot use `Array.filter` directly since `isChosen` is not a function of `A` elements and there is no `Array.filteri` like `Array.mapi`.

Comment: Sounds like [`zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353408.aspx) might be handy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

zip should help:

```
let l = [|1;2;3|]
let f = [|true; false; true|]

let r = [| for (v, f) in Seq.zip l f do if f then yield v|]
// or
let r = (l, f) ||> Seq.zip |> Seq.filter snd |> Seq.map fst |> Seq.toArray
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the zip operator

```
seq.zip A isChosen 
|> Seq.filter snd
|> Seq.map fst
|> Array.ofSeq
```

This will create a sequence of tuples where one value is from `A` and the other is from `isChosen`.  This will pair the values together and make it very easy to filter them out in a `Seq.filter` expression

Comment: +1, but note that `Seq.filter (fun (_, right) -> right)` could be simplified to `Seq.filter snd` and likewise for `Seq.map (fun (left, _) -> left)` to `Seq.map fst`.

Comment: @ildjam thanks for the recomendation. I often forget about the tuple helpers

Answer (score 2):

It's not as elegant or 'functional' as the other answers, but every once in a while I like a gentle reminder that you can use loops and array indices in F#:

```
let A = [|1;2;3|]
let isChosen = [|true; false; true|]
let r = [| for i in 0..A.Length-1 do 
                if isChosen.[i] then 
                    yield A.[i] |]
printfn "%A" r
```

:)

Comment: my first try was using `->` rather than `do.. yield`. why `->` wont work? thanks

Comment: You can replace `do yield` with `->` as 'short form' syntax if you are doing a simple one-liner mapping, but if you have any logic (like the `if`) then there is no 'short form'.  (I dislike the 'short form' syntax, it adds little value, and creates confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

And here are two more ways, just to demonstrate (even) more F# library functions:

```
let A = [|1;2;3|]
let isChosen = [|true;false;true|]

let B = Seq.map2 (fun x b -> if b then Some x else None) A isChosen
        |> Seq.choose id
        |> Seq.toArray

let C = Array.foldBack2 (fun x b acc -> if b then x::acc else acc) A isChosen []
        |> List.toArray
```

My personal favorite for understandability (and therefore maintainability): desco's answer

```
let r = [| for (v, f) in Seq.zip l f do if f then yield v|]
```